# Huge Wallch icon in Xubuntu 14.04 (xfce-panel)

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, xfce, panel, wallch

I have strange problem. My Wallch icon is huge. See the screenshot:

[image]

I removed XFCE settings and reordered items a little. How can I restore normal Wallch icon size?

**Update**:

My `/usr/share/applications/wallch-nautilus.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=4
Name=Wallch
Comment=Change desktop wallpapers automatically
Exec=/usr/bin/wallch %U
Icon=wallch
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
MimeType=inode/directory;

Actions=Change_Wallpaper;Start;

[Desktop Action Change_Wallpaper]
Name=Change Wallpaper Once
Exec=/usr/bin/wallch --change
TargetEnvironmet=Unity

[Desktop Action Start]
Name=Start/Stop Wallpapers
Exec=/usr/bin/wallch --start
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

And the `/usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png`:

[image]

Comment: I don't use XFCE, but I recommend 1. Removing and readding whatever Wallch is to your panel; and 2. Investigating the XFCE panel config files.

Comment: @blujay I was able to solve the problem. See the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to set my wallch icon size to normal. How I did that:

1. Opened `/usr/share/wallch/files/indicator_radiance_normal.png` in Gimp.
2. Resized it to 24x24. Saved the original as `indicator_radiance_normal_64x64.png` and the edited as `indicator_radiance_normal.png`
3. Restarted Wallch.

Now it looks exactly how it should:

[image]

Also, I posted [bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wallch/+bug/1313531) and it came out that it is not a Wallch bug, but `xfce4-indicator-plugin` bug.

Comment: Nicely done.  Seems like a bug though: it should have resized the image appropriately.  You might consider filing it as a bug on Launchpad or wherever wallch bugs are tracked.

Comment: OK, I will submit bugreport.

Comment: That's not a Wallch bug. It is a XUbuntu bug. I talked to them on IRC about it.

Comment: @hakermania, I am Hopungo Semi-bit on Launchpad ;)

Comment: @Danatela I know ;)