# Prime Indicator enormous in xfce-panel

Tags: indicator, xfce, xfce-panel, nvidia-prime

I installed `prime-indicator`, which allows to quickly switch between Intel and Nvidia graphics cards, as reported here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

No problems with **Unity** or **Gnome Shell**, but here what happens in `xfce4` environment, with the appindicator plugin:

[image]

How to solve?

Comment: I had a similar issue. [Check out this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456728/huge-wallch-icon-in-xubuntu-14-04?rq=1) for a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize these images:

```
sudo convert /usr/lib/primeindicator/intel.png -resize 24x24 /usr/lib/primeindicator/intel.png
sudo convert /usr/lib/primeindicator/nvidia.png -resize 24x24 /usr/lib/primeindicator/nvidia.png
```